# How can I invoke system functions from native code on AIX?

Tags: c, mono, aix, jit

My purpose is invoke a system call or libc functions from native code.
The native code is a executable memory block which I insert some machine code into it. In the native code I try to invoke puts() or printf() functions to output a string. Then I call the native code. This sequence model is the Mono tries to do. But when I porting the Mono into AIX, I met a segment fault when invokes system library functions such as printf() or abs(). I guess it must break calling stack somewhere. But I could not resolve such problem I am not familiar with IBM powerpc platform.
I have wrote a simple program to demonstrate the sequence, it also lead to segment fault at calling puts(). It takes so much time, please give me some advises, thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


typedef uint8_t        guint8;
typedef int16_t        gint16;
typedef uint16_t       guint16;
typedef int32_t        gint32;
typedef uint32_t       guint32;
typedef int64_t        gint64;
typedef uint64_t       guint64;
typedef float          gfloat;
typedef double         gdouble;
typedef int32_t        gboolean;
typedef void *         gpointer;
typedef enum {
        ppc_r0 = 0,
        ppc_r1,
        ppc_sp = ppc_r1,
        ppc_r2,
        ppc_r3,
        ppc_r4,
        ppc_r5,
        ppc_r6,
        ppc_r7,
        ppc_r8,
        ppc_r9,
        ppc_r10,
        ppc_r11,
        ppc_r12,
        ppc_r13,
        ppc_r14,
        ppc_r15,
        ppc_r16,
        ppc_r17,
        ppc_r18,
        ppc_r19,
        ppc_r20,
        ppc_r21,
        ppc_r22,
        ppc_r23,
        ppc_r24,
        ppc_r25,
        ppc_r26,
        ppc_r27,
        ppc_r28,
        ppc_r29,
        ppc_r30,
        ppc_r31
} PPCIntRegister;
typedef enum {
        ppc_lr = 256,
        ppc_ctr = 256 + 32,
        ppc_xer = 32
} PPCSpecialRegister;
#define G_STMT_START    do
#define G_STMT_END      while (0)
#define ppc_load32(c,D,v) G_STMT_START {        \
                ppc_lis ((c), (D),      (guint32)(v) >> 16);    \
                ppc_ori ((c), (D), (D), (guint32)(v) & 0xffff); \
        } G_STMT_END
#define ppc_emit32(c,x) do { *((guint32 *) (c)) = (guint32) (x); (c) = (gpointer)((guint8 *)(c) + sizeof (    guint32));} while (0)
#define ppc_stwux(c,S,A,B) ppc_emit32(c, (31 << 26) | (S << 21) | (A << 16) | (B << 11) | (183 << 1) | 0)
#define    ppc_or(c,a,s,b) ppc_emit32 (c, (31 << 26) | ((s) << 21) | ((a) << 16) | ((b) << 11) | 888)
#define    ppc_mr(c,a,s)   ppc_or     (c, a, s, s)
#define   ppc_ori(c,S,A,ui) ppc_emit32 (c, (24 << 26) | ((S) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(ui))
#define ppc_addis(c,D,A,i) ppc_emit32 (c, (15 << 26) | ((D) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(i))
#define   ppc_lis(c,D,v)   ppc_addis  (c, D, 0, (guint16)(v))
#define ppc_load_sequence(c,D,v) ppc_load32 ((c), (D), (guint32)(v))
#define ppc_load_func(c,D,V)          ppc_load_sequence ((c), (D), (V))
#define ppc_mtspr(c,spr,S) ppc_emit32 (c, (31 << 26) | ((S) << 21) | ((spr) << 11) | (467 << 1))
#define  ppc_mtlr(c,S)     ppc_mtspr  (c, ppc_lr, S)
#define  ppc_blrl(c)       ppc_emit32 (c, 0x4e800021)
#define ppc_mfspr(c,D,spr) ppc_emit32 (c, (31 << 26) | ((D) << 21) | ((spr) << 11) | (339 << 1))
#define  ppc_mflr(c,D)     ppc_mfspr  (c, D, ppc_lr)
#define   ppc_stw(c,S,d,A) ppc_emit32 (c, (36 << 26) | ((S) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(d))
#define  ppc_stwu(c,s,d,A) ppc_emit32 (c, (37 << 26) | ((s) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(d))
#define  ppc_addi(c,D,A,i) ppc_emit32 (c, (14 << 26) | ((D) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(i))
#define   ppc_lwz(c,D,d,A) ppc_emit32 (c, (32 << 26) | ((D) << 21) | ((A) << 16) | (guint16)(d))
#define   ppc_blr(c)       ppc_emit32 (c, 0x4e800020)
#define  ppc_bl(c,li)       ppc_emit32 (c, (18 << 26) | ((li) << 2) | 1)
#define PPC_CALL_REG ppc_r12

void foo()
{
  puts("Hello");
}

int main() 
{
  unsigned char codebuf [1024];
  unsigned char* code;
  void * mem;
  unsigned char* codest;
  void *values[1];
  int rc;

  foo();
  code = codest = codebuf;
  ppc_load_func(code, PPC_CALL_REG, *((void **)foo));
  ppc_mtlr(code, PPC_CALL_REG);
  ppc_blrl(code);

  mem = mmap(NULL, code - codest, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
    MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
  memcpy(mem, codest, code - codest);
  void (*func) () = &mem;
  func();  

  return 0;
}
```

I must use gcc. the macros were copied from Mono. func() is good when not call system library functions.
It could step into func(), but when invokes puts, the register R2 value somehow was manipulated. I don't know why? following is debug step on my test box :

```
127       func();
=> 0x10000760 <main+304>:       80 1f 00 40     lwz     r0,64(r31)
   0x10000764 <main+308>:       7c 0b 03 78     mr      r11,r0
   0x10000768 <main+312>:       81 2b 00 00     lwz     r9,0(r11)
   0x1000076c <main+316>:       90 41 00 14     stw     r2,20(r1)
   0x10000770 <main+320>:       7c 0a 03 78     mr      r10,r0
   0x10000774 <main+324>:       81 6a 00 08     lwz     r11,8(r10)
   0x10000778 <main+328>:       7d 29 03 a6     mtctr   r9
   0x1000077c <main+332>:       7c 0a 03 78     mr      r10,r0
   0x10000780 <main+336>:       80 4a 00 04     lwz     r2,4(r10)
   0x10000784 <main+340>:       4e 80 04 21     bctrl
   0x10000788 <main+344>:       80 41 00 14     lwz     r2,20(r1)
```

above is the point of entering func().
below is the core dump snapshot:

```
(gdb) 
    0x10000550      90        puts("Hello");
    0x1000054c <foo+20>: 80 62 00 58     lwz     r3,88(r2)
 => 0x10000550 <foo+24>: 48 00 03 41     bl      0x10000890 <puts>
    0x10000554 <foo+28>: 80 41 00 14     lwz     r2,20(r1)
(gdb) 
    0x10000890 in puts ()
 => 0x10000890 <puts+0>: 81 82 00 5c     lwz     r12,92(r2)
(gdb) 
    0x10000894 in puts ()
 => 0x10000894 <puts+4>: 90 41 00 14     stw     r2,20(r1)
(gdb) info reg r12
    r12            0x0      0
(gdb) ni
    0x10000898 in puts ()
 => 0x10000898 <puts+8>: 80 0c 00 00     lwz     r0,0(r12)
(gdb) 
    0x1000089c in puts ()
 => 0x1000089c <puts+12>:        80 4c 00 04     lwz     r2,4(r12)
(gdb) 
    0x100008a0 in puts ()
 => 0x100008a0 <puts+16>:        7c 09 03 a6     mtctr   r0
(gdb) info reg r0
    r0             0x0      0
(gdb) ni
    0x100008a4 in puts ()
 => 0x100008a4 <puts+20>:        4e 80 04 20     bctr
(gdb) 
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
    0x00000000 in ?? ()
 => 0x00000000:  00 00 00 00     .long 0x0
```

in puts(), it jump to wrong address 0x0, at the begining of func(), compiler has modified R2(*lwz     r2,4(r10)*), it leads to the problem, but it is compiler generated code, I can't change it. I don't know how to handle this issue. Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: What sort of malware will it be?

Comment: it is a part of JIT. The JIT generate native code(shell) then put a another native code into it then call the shell. Mono would use such pattern.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, I searched. it might be about function descriptor, But i couldn't find any official manual describes 32bits function descriptor. I noticed that function name points to a table called function descriptor, the table includes entry address, TOC address and third field(i don't know). It seems aix compiler put TOC address into R2 register (according to AIX ABI), this R2 was used to lookup global symbols. Because the dynamically generated function(like my example)  doesn't have TOC info, it destroyed the calling environment. How could I found 32bit AIX abi official manual? thks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand "glue code" and "glink code".

As a practical method, write just a simple program where main calls puts.  Then look at the assembly produced as well as single step (i.e. stepi) through the code.

The "function pointer" puts() does not point to the executable when it is in another module.  Instead it points to a toc entry that has three entries: the address of the function, the toc of the module, and another value that I can't recall.  The glue code / glink code (IIRC) takes a pointer in r11 to this entry and it will then correctly call the destination function.

Upon return, the next instruction after the bl will be an instruction to restore the toc.

The compiler, ld, as well as the loader all participate in the magic to make this happen.

Happy hunting...